# Javascript this.form.submit() with radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have this star rating system for my webpage, where you can select a star rating (1-5) and i wanted to send the form when someone clicks any of the stars, but right now, it does not send the radio button value if i check something, i think its because it sends the form before it checks the radio button. Is there any better way to send the form with the radio button value onclick?

```html
<form method="POST" action="/rating" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="vySkIFDPujcmxjfs83m3OwojcbPIaHuuMhKvVErx">

        <input name="movie_id" type="hidden" value="2">


        <input id="star5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5">
        <label for="star5" class="full" title="Awesome" onclick="this.form.submit()"> </label>


        <input id="star4" name="rating" type="radio" value="4">
        <label for="star4" class="full" title="Good" onclick="this.form.submit()"> </label>


        <input id="star3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3">
        <label for="star3" class="full" title="Mediocre" onclick="this.form.submit()"> </label>


        <input id="star2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2">
        <label for="star2" class="full" title="Bad" onclick="this.form.submit()"> </label>


        <input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1">
        <label for="star1" class="full" title="Horrible" onclick="this.form.submit()"> </label>

        </form>
```

Comment: change it to onchange and see what happens

Comment: Just use regular submit buttons. Don't use JS to try to make a radio button into a submit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onchange` on the `<input />` elements instead:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/rating" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="vySkIFDPujcmxjfs83m3OwojcbPIaHuuMhKvVErx">

  <input name="movie_id" type="hidden" value="2">

  <label for="star5" class="full" title="Awesome">
<input id="star5" name="rating" type="radio" value="5" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </label>

  <label for="star4" class="full" title="Good">
<input id="star4" name="rating" type="radio" value="4" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </label>

  <label for="star3" class="full" title="Mediocre">
<input id="star3" name="rating" type="radio" value="3" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </label>

  <label for="star2" class="full" title="Bad">
<input id="star2" name="rating" type="radio" value="2" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </label>

  <label for="star1" class="full" title="Horrible">
<input id="star1" name="rating" type="radio" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  </label>

</form>
```

Comment: with onchange it doesnt send the form at all :\

Comment: `<label>` doesn't have `onchange` event

Comment: put the onChange event on the `<input />` element.

Comment: yeah i figued, i am dumb. i used it on the radio button input and it works now, thank you. Even onclick works now with it.

Comment: @dentora it's cool, the code in the answer is using the label... :-)  Nothing dumb about it.  Only suggestion might be to intercept the form post and do it in JS so that it doesn't need to do the full round trip to the server on selection.

Comment: Thanks @Tracker1, I'm always glad when someone likes my way of doing things.